# I try to input a number into an array but it doesn't work

Tags: python, arrays, integer

```
Tally = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Choice = int
while Choice != 0:
    Choice = input("Prompt: enter hobby")
    int(Choice)
    Tally[Choice] = Tally[Choice] + 1
for Index in range(1, 5, 1):
    print (Tally[Index])
```

When I try to input a number it says that it must be an integer or slice, not string. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: `Choice = int`??? That is not what you want to do. That sets the `Choice` variable to the `int` type. Maybe `Choice = int(input())`?

Comment: You forgot to assign the result of `int(Choice)` back to `Choice`. `Choice = int(Choice)`

Comment: It would be nice to have the full error output here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the line

```
Choice = int
```

should be

```
Choice = 1
```

Or any other number other than 0. This is because `int` is a class, so you are setting the variable `Choice` to the class `int`, not making a variable of type `int`. Secondly, you didn't save the int value of `Choice`. You need to change

```
int(Choice)
```

to

```
Choice = int(Choice)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do:

```
Choice = int(input("Prompt: enter hobby"))
```

Which takes the input and converts it to an int immediately on the same line, before Choice is assigned.